# Cannot use dismiss on modally presented view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

**Edit:**

I went back and tried to recreate the connection and discovered that the builder is forcing me to connect it as an Exit object rather than a View Controller object. I have no idea why its doing this, and even after scrapping the old button and creating a new one it's still forcing me. So I've found the cause of the initial problem but can't figure out root cause.

[image: no description]

**Original post:**

Every screen in my current project is presented modally and I use the following to dismiss the view controller when a button is pressed:

```
    @IBAction func close(){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So far it has worked perfectly, except for the very last view I had to create. I've checked my segue and it is set to present modally like all the others. I've checked and double-checked the other segue configurations as well as the view configurations. They're identical to the other views. I'm at a total loss. Just wondering if anyone has ever had this happen or has any suggestions that I may have overlooked. For the hell of it I tried `self.dismiss()` and it didn't make a difference.

My storyboard layout is somewhat hub-and-spoke in nature, in other words the main view controller is top-level and then the remaining views are secondary and have no relation to each other, only to the main view.

Here's the segue settings for the view controller in question:

[image: Current segue settings for view]

Comment: this last viewController that you implemented, what is different about it then the others?

Comment: are you trying to dismiss a view? or a view controller? In your question you say view.

Comment: First note my edit above regarding the Exit object. To answer your question, literally the only major difference is that on the last viewController I did not declare UITextFieldDelegate in addition to UIViewController, but the last viewController doesn't need it. Otherwise they're very similar.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri good catch - trying to dismiss view controller that is presented modally. Will edit original post.

Comment: this EXIT object, can you clarify what you are doing to get this ? Are you creating an IBAction from the button ?

Comment: also, are you calling your IBAction within the presented view controller that you want to dismiss ? If not, that is where you should be doin git

Comment: It really shouldn't matter whether you're in the presented controller or not.  See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated).  Maybe you're programmatically calling `close()` from a background thread?  Or possibly the view is detached from the hierarchy somehow?

Comment: Figured it out and I feel like an idiot. I didn't have the view controller connected to the view controller class in my swift file. Every moment is a learning moment.

Comment: try self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)